# How do I install ca-certificates-mono?

Tags: mono

I'm trying to install ca-certificates-mono on linux mint:

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates-mono
```

Unfortunately I'm getting this error. I'm trying to follow the instructions here(tried the ubuntu one, since it seems closest): http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ca-certificates-mono : Depends: libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but 3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: `libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1)` is this version available in your repositories? why not install mono and ca-certificates from the ubuntu repositories?